# Stylus for Multitouch (Laptop) Trackpad?

Tags: multi-touch, peripheral

I remember seeing a stylus that was available for the multitouch (laptop) trackpad. I'm learning a new language right now so it would be rather useful to be able to use a stylus to 'write' instead of using my fingers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the oStylus Capacitive Drawing Stylus:

http://ostylus.com/

Engadget's review specifically mentions and shows the stylus being used with Apple's Magic Trackpad.

http://www.engadget.com/2010/10/01/ostylus-capacitive-pen-review/